# Apply StopWordsRemover and RegexTokenizer to multiple columns in spark 2.4.3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've the following dataframe, df4

```
|Itemno   |fits_assembly_id                                        |fits_assembly_name                                                                         |assembly_name 

|0450056  |13039 135502 141114 4147 138865 2021 9164               |OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY A01EA09CA 4999202399920239A06 A02EA09CA A02EA09CB A02EA09CC              |OIL PUMP ASSEMBLY 999202399920239A06
```

and I am using following code to process/clean the above-mentioned data frame

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover, RegexTokenizer
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr


# Task-1: Regex Tokenizer

tk = RegexTokenizer(pattern=r'(?:\p{Punct}|\s)+', inputCol='fits_assembly_name', outputCol='temp1')
df5 = tk.transform(df4)

#Task-2: StopWordsRemover
sw = StopWordsRemover(inputCol='temp1', outputCol='temp2')
df6 = sw.transform(df5)

# #Task-3: Remove duplicates
df7 = df6.withColumn('fits_assembly_name', expr('concat_ws(" ", array_distinct(temp2))')) \
            .drop('temp1', 'temp2')
```

I want to process both columns `fits_assembly_name` and `assembly_name` in `RegexTokenizer & StopWordsRemover` in one go. Could you please share how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to handle multiple columns, use [pyspark.ml.Pipeline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/ml-pipeline.html) to skip the intermediate dataframes, see below:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover, RegexTokenizer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

# df4 is the initial dataframe and new result will overwrite it.
for col in ['fits_assembly_name', 'assembly_name']:
    tk = RegexTokenizer(pattern=r'(?:\p{Punct}|\s)+', inputCol=col, outputCol='temp1')
    sw = StopWordsRemover(inputCol='temp1', outputCol='temp2')
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tk, sw])
    df4 = pipeline.fit(df4).transform(df4) \
        .withColumn(col, expr('concat_ws(" ", array_distinct(temp2))')) \
        .drop('temp1', 'temp2')
```

Comment: I've asked ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920120/apache-scala-spark-2-4-4-group-data-by-year-range-to-generate-analyze-new-featu```. If possible, could you please assist and share some good scala dataframe learning resouces as well.

Comment: Hi, @SachinSharma, I am not familiar with Scala programming, so won't be able to recommend you on this topic :(

Comment: Could you please help me using python? I can use that logic and will translate it into scala at my end.

Comment: Just changed the question to suggest solution in python or scala.