# Apache Scala/Python Spark 2.4.4: Group data by year range to generate/analyze new feature

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've following data frame which I generated for feature engineering and now in order to drive another feature, I am trying to create `purchaseYearRange` column where I want to create a column with 3 year range and aggregate `modelRatio, purchaseRatio` values by `itemNo, modelnumber and valueClass columns`.

**E.g.:** For **itemNo#7010032**, we will have a row with 1995-1996-1997 value in new `purchaseYearRange` column and `modelRatio, purchaseRatio` values for these years will be summed up in the respective row. Next, I'll do that same for next 3 years which will be 1996-1997-1998, 1997-1998-1999, etc.

Also, this item has one row with `itemClass - RGR`, for that row we'll only have that row with 1996 data.

**Basically, check for 3 years data in dataframe and if it exists then sum `modelRatio, purchaseRatio` for three-year range window. If three-year data doesn't exist then sum for two or one year based on data availability.**

- DataFrame

```
| itemNo|modelnumber|itemClass |purchaseYear|          ModelRatio|      PurchaseRatio|
+-------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|1321457|  A99AA25CA|       ATV|        1995|   1.801325096248545|                2.0|
|7010032|  A99AA25CB|       ATV|        1995|  1.0048348106365834|                2.0|
|7010032|  A99AA25CB|       ATV|        1996|  0.8899632912525741|                2.0|
|7010032|  A99AA25CB|       RGR|        1996|  0.7899632912525741|                1.0| 
|7010032|  A99AA25CB|       ATV|        1997|   1.669710806697108|                2.0|  
|7010032|  A99AA25CB|       ATV|        1998|  0.9982988629241651|                2.0| 
|7010032|  A99AA25CB|       ATV|        1999|0.006535947712418301|                1.0|
|7552901|  A99AA25CD|       ATV|        1995|   37.83901871250784|               12.0| 
|7552901|  A99AA25CD|       ATV|        1996|0.026143790849673203|                1.0|
|7552901|  A99AA25CD|       ATV|        1997|  0.9375951293759512|                2.0|
```

I am new to scala spark and tried it using `.createOrReplaceTempView("test") and then apply SQL operations` but it is super complex this way. Could you please share how I can get it done. **Please feel free to suggest solution in Python and or in Scala**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use Spark SQL [Window function](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/select.html#window-functions) as following: (make sure the purchaseYear is a numeric or timestamp column)

**Edit:** per comments, added all_puchase_years to include 3-year sequence. Notice that `ORDER BY itemNo, purchaseYear` clause is only for demonstration purpose.

```
spark.sql(""" 
       SELECT itemNo 
       ,      modelnumber 
       ,      itemClass 
       ,      concat_ws('-', sort_array(collect_set(purchaseYear) OVER w1)) AS purchase_years 
       ,      concat_ws('-', sequence(purchaseYear, purchaseYear+2)) AS all_purchase_years
       ,      sum(PurchaseRatio) OVER w1 AS sum_PurchaseRatio 
       ,      sum(ModelRatio) OVER w1 AS sum_ModelRatio 
       FROM test 
       ORDER BY itemNo, purchaseYear 
       WINDOW w1 AS (
           PARTITION BY (itemNo, modelnumber, itemClass)  
           ORDER BY purchaseYear 
           RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING
       ) 
""").show() 
#+-------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
#| itemNo|modelnumber|itemClass|purchase_years|sum_PurchaseRatio|      sum_ModelRatio|
#+-------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
#|1321457|  A99AA25CA|      ATV|          1995|              2.0|   1.801325096248545|
#|7010032|  A99AA25CB|      ATV|1995-1996-1997|              6.0|   3.564508908586266|
#|7010032|  A99AA25CB|      RGR|          1996|              1.0|  0.7899632912525741|
#|7010032|  A99AA25CB|      ATV|1996-1997-1998|              6.0|  3.5579729608738475|
#|7010032|  A99AA25CB|      ATV|1997-1998-1999|              5.0|  2.6745456173336914|
#|7010032|  A99AA25CB|      ATV|     1998-1999|              3.0|  1.0048348106365834|
#|7010032|  A99AA25CB|      ATV|          1999|              1.0|0.006535947712418301|
#|7552901|  A99AA25CD|      ATV|1995-1996-1997|             15.0|   38.80275763273346|
#|7552901|  A99AA25CD|      ATV|     1996-1997|              3.0|  0.9637389202256245|
#|7552901|  A99AA25CD|      ATV|          1997|              2.0|  0.9375951293759512|
#+-------+-----------+---------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Just realized query is using ```current and 2 following```. So if there is data for 2005, 2007 and 2008 but not for 2006, it'll do 2005-2007-2008 and sum values for that. To avoid this can you suggest how we insert ```0 for missing entries``` and then apply above logic so it's always considering three consecutive years and summing them up. E.g. in second last row, insert record for missing 1995 by copying itemNo, modelnumber and itemClass and putting 0 in modelRatio and purchaseRatio column and then apply above-mentioned logic.

Comment: @SachinSharma, we are using `RANGE` between which is the offset not the Row numbers, thus it should pick up the next 2 years, and I believe 2008 should be excluded from 2005-2007.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I was thinking of making ```purchase_year``` have 3 years so that It'll look consistent in labels. Even If data is for two or one years, ```purchase_year``` is always in ```YYYY-YYYY-YYYY``` format and represents which years were considered while summing it up so the business side knows it's always three years. I am figuring it out at my end but if it's simple fix then let me know the fix.